# Google Maps Autocomplete and Bounds

Tags: google-maps

I want auto complete results only from Mexico, for this I am trying the code below and adding bounds to ensure put Mexico in a rectangle, however I still get resutlts from outside of the country.

How Can I fix this ?

Here is the [html](http://pastehtml.com/view/bhzzgiq8r.html) and the same code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Test: Places Autocomplete</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
      type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      #map_canvas {
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        display:hidden;
      }
     #searchTextField{
        width:500px;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {

        var options = { 
          bounds: google.maps.LatLngBounds( google.maps.LatLng(33.1613, -118.4766), google.maps.LatLng(14.3770, -84.8145) )     
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50"> <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now you can accomplish what you want with:

```
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'mx'}
```

in your `options` argument to build the `Autocomplete` object.

This is a hard restriction, unlike `bounds`.  It's only for countries, but that's what you want anyway.

Comment: This is the preferable way to get results only from one country.

Your solution was not working because the bounds were not set properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
    var options = {
        types:  ['geocode'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: "mx"}
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the bounds is not how you do location biasing. See "Location Biasing" in this documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#location_biasing

> You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a
>   radius parameter. Doing so instructs the Place service to prefer
>   showing results within that circle; results outside of the defined
>   area may still be displayed.

Also, take a look at this sample here:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/places/places-search.html

I should also, note, I don't think it's possible to just specify "Mexico only". You can do searches within a radius, but you can't specify just a country.

Comment: Your first statement about location biasing isn't for V3 I think. The documentation for [V3 autocomplete options](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#AutocompleteOptions) does say to use bounds to bias the results.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer suggested and as it says in the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#AutocompleteOptions), you can only **bias** towards a set of results. I would suggest making a smaller bounds based on somewhere in the middle of Mexico or even Mexico City to make the bias stronger.